# GET-only api for Google Sheets or similar

Tags: tableau-api, google-sheets-api

I have a Tableau workbook that helps surface interesting cases in a large dataset.  Once an interesting case is identified, I'd like to add it to an external list that allows me to take action on it later.  Ideally, I'd like to use the URL action to drive a separate app, like Google Sheets, and add a line with the ID of the currently selected item.  Like this completely made-up example:

`http://sheets.googleapis.com/SheetName?op=AddRow&data={id:123,title:"foo"}`

I can do all of these things in Tableau to get the URL built how I want, but I am stuck with just an http GET, with no post payload.  I don't see any way to get google sheets to work with a simple GET request.

Questions:

- Is there any way to get Google Sheets to behave how I want, where I
  can add a row with just a GET request?  I can't find anything in the docs that would suggest this is possible.
- Is there an alternative to Google Sheets that I can use that is authenticated?  (OneNote, for example, seems to have the same POST limitation)
- Is there some sort of intermediary I can use to bridge the divide, like IFTTT?  I can't seem to figure out a way to kick off an IFTTT type of action with just a GET request from a browser.

Answer (score 1):

As @noogui explained, Google Sheets uses standard REST methods for interacting with sheets. You could write your own web application wrapper around Google Sheets, allowing a GET that would then interact with Google Sheets' POST method. The wrapper can be in any language that allows http calls.

You don't specify if you want the action to work only in Desktop or also in Server. If Desktop only, you could easily write your wrapper in Javascript and run it locally. If also running it in Server, choose your favorite web programming language, fire up an application server, and point your action URL to the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

The available option in Sheets v4 as mentioned in [Insert an empty row or column](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/rowcolumn#insert_an_empty_row_or_column) is to use [spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate). That's a POST request and not a GET request. GET requests are for reading purposes only or as mentioned [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp), to retrieve data. Whenever you're writing, you use POST or PUT methods so I don't what you're doing is possible thru GET.